# How to speed up per column iteration

Tags: r, performance, data.table, iteration, vectorization

I would like to loop through a data.table and apply a function that requires info from another column in the data.table, sometimes even multiple...

Let's take the mtcars as an example

I have the feeling that you can stick to the .SD way but provide extra arguments and make this much more efficient...

```
require(data.table)
dt = data.table(mtcars)

#looping through columns of mtcars...
cols = c('mpg', 'hp', 'disp')
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) x/mean(x)), .SDcols=cols]

# But actually I want to devide x by the mean of x where am==1

# Now I am doing this...

specificMean= function(DT) {
  x = DT$feature
  xAM = DT[AM==1]$feature
  MEAN = mean(xAM, na.rm=TRUE)
  x = x/MEAN    
  return(x)
}

dt[,(cols):=lapply(cols, function(x) specificMean(data.table(feature=get(x), AM=am))), .SDcols=cols]
print(dt)
```

I have the feeling this is much slower because it performs the data.table() function in each iteration...

A vectorized solution would be nice..

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach:

```
dt[, (cols) := mapply(`/`, .SD[,-"am"], lapply(.SD[am==1, -"am"], mean), SIMPLIFY=FALSE), 
    .SDcols=c("am", cols)]
```

Comment: Thank you @chinsoon12, this is a more efficient and faster approach, although not simple syntax...

Comment: Adding a summary dt would make it look simpler:

```dt_mean <- dt[am == 1, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols];```

```dt[, mapply('/', .SD, dt_mean), .SDcols = cols]```

Comment: Or even better, use my solution's approach as it seems as though ```am``` is available in the ```.SD``` even if it's not in the listed ```.SDcols```. This is about 10x faster than the Wienand's original and about 40% faster than mine:    ```dt[, mapply('/', .SD, lapply(.SD[am==1,], mean)), .SDcols = cols]```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This seems to produce the same result as yours.

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(mtcars)
cols = c('mpg', 'hp', 'disp')

dt[, (cols) := .SD / lapply(.SD[am == 1], mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Sorry Cole, this is not what I had in mind... I want to iterate through cols and devide each column by the mean of the column where 'am' equals 1
In your solution the records that are still in there are correct but all the others that are excluded because of 
``am == 1``
are not included and should also be devided by the same number

Comment: See edit. The output is the same as yours now and kinda looks like ```x / mean(x)```.

Answer (score 0):

`system.time(dt[,lapply(cols, function(x) specificMean(data.table(feature=get(x), AM=am))), .SDcols=cols])`

user  system elapsed 
0.010   0.000   0.005

## efficient way using two loop thanks to @chinsoon12

`` system.time(dt[,mapply(`/`, .SD[,-"am"], lapply(.SD[am==1, -"am"], mean), SIMPLIFY=FALSE), .SDcols=c("am", cols)]) ``

user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001

## The winning efficient way using one loop thanks to @Cole

`system.time(dt[,.SD / lapply(.SD[am == 1], mean, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols])`

user  system elapsed 
0.001   0.000   0.001

Comment: ```microbenchmark``` is a good library to run timing. It would have shown that @chinsoon12's solution was faster as its results are in milliseconds (or whatever unit is most appropriate). Also, if these are solutions, you should select one as the answer.